# Вопрос по Arrays.fill

Tags: java

Что делает

```
Arrays.fill(visited, false);
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заполняет все элементы массива `visited` значением `false`. JavaDoc вам в помощь.